# Selecting a entry in my drop down and trying to add the data to the particular entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

`    <SFX:DropDownListEx ID="GNRType" runat="server" CssClass="gen_field_text" AutoPostBack="true" OnChange="SetValue()" OnChangeSource="OnChangeType"> </SFX:DropDownListEx> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqGNRType" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddConfig"SetFocusOnError="true

Stored Procedure

SELECT 'GNRType','gvConfigList','' SELECT '--SELECT--' AS description, '' AS Code UNION ALL SELECT distinct GNR_Type as description,GNR_Type as code FROM EFT_Config END ELSE BEGIN SELECT 'gvConfigList','' END SELECT GNR_EntityId AS EntityID, GNR_Slno AS Slno, GNR_Type AS [GNRType], GNR_ParentCode AS ParentCode,GNR_Code AS Code, GNR_Description AS [Description], GNR_CreatedBy, GNR_ModifiedBy, GNR_ApprovedBy, GNR_CreatedOn, GNR_ModifiedOn, GNR_ApprovedOn FROM EFT_Config WHERE GNR_Type = @GNRType ORDER BY [GNRType],Slno

Selecting a entry in my drop down and trying to add the data to the particular entry which i have selected from the drop down the entry is creating a empty entry in drop down

[image]

and the newly added values coming in the empty drop down entry

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow mate, sorry but you forgot to ask a question. please post the code that you have written and describe the problem that you have with this code.

Comment: Hi bro Thanks for replying.. What code do you want aspx page or stored procedures?? @MongZhu

Comment: @PrabhuKnightrider Please do not post pictures of the code. Rather put the actual code to get better responses.

Comment: @PrabhuKnightrider Can you please post this code on your question and not the comment section?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

well, you could consider just the add button, and then add the new row, and in that row, you would have the drop down, and they select it that way.

But, I suppose you can have that drop down - but you ALSO probably have/want that drop down in the row of data for editing also, right?

You also don't mention if you using a grid view, or a list view for the rows of data? So, it kind of hard to guess what control and how you filled that grid in the first place, and then that of adding rows to the grid, right?

So, we have to take a wild guess here - lets use a grid view.

Also, your dropdown list don't like like a regular asp.net one either. Are you using some 3rd party controls here? (again: a REALLY huge issue to leave out, right?).

Ok, So we have to make a few 100's of guess here, but we will assume a dropdown list for the combo box, and we will assume a grid view for the grid.

so, we have this markup:

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select City for Hotel to add" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" style="margin-left:15px"
            DataValueField="City"
            DataTextField="City" Height="20px" Width="216px" AutoPostBack="True" 
            >
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" cssclass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City"        HeaderText="City"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />                    
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

So, we have a combo box (drop down list), and a grid view.

The code to load up the grid view is thus this:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadData()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT City from City ORDER BY City", conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim rstCity As New DataTable
            rstCity.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            cboCity.DataSource = rstCity
            cboCity.DataBind()
            cboCity.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--SELECT--", "--SELECT--"))

            ' Now load our grid data
            cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * from tblHotels  ORDER BY HotelName"
            Dim rstGrid As New DataTable
            rstGrid.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstGrid
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using

    End Using

End Sub
```

And now we have this:

[image]

Now, lets write the code for the  combo box. We will select  value in this case city, and then add the new row to the data and the grid.

So, dropdown assumed to have auto post back, and then for the selected index change event, we have this code:

```
Protected Sub cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboCity.SelectedIndexChanged

    ' User selected a city - lets add the data row

    If cboCity.SelectedItem.Text <> "--SELECT--" Then

        Dim strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblhotels (City, Active) VALUES (@City, True)"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
            Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCity.SelectedItem.Text
                conn.Open()
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using

        ' reload grid to show new row added
        LoadData()
    End If

End Sub
```

So, now I can select a value from the combo box, and the new row will now be added to the grid. We would thus say see this:

[image]

The code will add the new data row, load grid, and now we have this:

[image]